# How do I bypass "TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType" message on Python on the mac terminal (BUSCO)

Tags: python, string

I am trying to run BUSCO using a FASTA file using my mac commandline. Unfortunately when doing so I receive the following message:

$ busco -i /Volumes/WORK/research_project/pseudomonas_putida/ncbi-genomes-2018-10-24/GCA_000007565.2_ASM756v2_genomic.fna -o /users/williamimart/Desktop/test -l //Volumes/WORK/research_project/busco_datasets/gammaproteobacteria_odb9 -m geno
Maximum number of regions limited to: 3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/williamimart/miniconda2/bin/busco", line 204, in 
    if mode == 'genome' and os.access(os.environ.get('AUGUSTUS_CONFIG_PATH'),os.W_OK) == False:
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, NoneType found

What can I do to go around this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you'll need to export the `AUGUSTUS_CONFIG_PATH`. The `os.environ.get()` is a place that could return `None` if you don't have that variable configured

The default value for that is not something clear to me as I don't have experience with this library, but the way to add that would be to run

`export AUGUSTUS_CONFIG_PATH=/some/path/to/conf`

Check their docs for what to set that path value to

Comment: Thank you very much. I've encountered new problems now but at least that one is resolved.